# Find/replace in TextEdit?

Tags: text, textedit

How can I change all occurrences of one string to another in TextEdit?

Other text editors call this "find/replace".

Comment: This question was linked from a related (hot network) question on User Experience: http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/94295/80480

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit Menu > Find, or <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

The Find dialog has a "Replace" section in it, and a "Replace All" button.

[image]

Comment: No wonder I couldn't find it... I was looking for a menu item called "replace".